# Porting AllJoyn Thin Core Source 15.09.00a to ThreadX/FreeRTOS

Tags: alljoyn

I have evaluation board with Host MCU + WIFI + Bluetooth together.

I want to port AllJoyn Thin Client services to this platform running with ThreadX/FreeRTOS.

Before that I would like get some details on the AllJoyn thin client source files, their dependency ( to RTOS, Network Stack, etc ) and may be a pointers ( other than the video sources which gives theoretical knowledge and overview on AllJoyn from AllSeen Alliance ) to some documents which give more technical overvierw.

Does anyone done this porting activity on any platform ( whether it is Standard Core Source on Linux platform as well ) ?

Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is more easy to think AllJoyn Thin Core Library (AjTCL) as a small subset of AllJoyn Standard Core Library (AjSCL). AjTCL is designed to work best with constrained embedded systems which run on RTOS like platforms with limited hardware specs.

[AjTCL library](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/learn/core/thin-core) designed with abstraction in mind, provides high level APIs to the application developer. But there are some target platform dependent interfaces that they should be implemented in compliance with the target platform.

If you want to run AjTCL on a specific embedded platform (Arduino, MBed, WICED, FreeRTOS etc.), then you must port (implement) these target dependent interfaces so that AllJoyn Thin Library utilizes the platform and continues to function as promised.

AjTCL Target dependent interfaces are;

```
target/aj_net.h // Network operations (TCP/UDP etc.)
target/aj_target.h // Target platform constants
target/aj_target_crypto.h // Security operations
target/aj_target_nvram.h // Persistent layer operations non-volatile ram 
target/aj_target_util.h // Target platform utility functions
```

Happy porting!